# Multiplication table with for loop with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

please help me to figure out how to organize my result in rows of 10 numbers and create the look multiplication tables from 1 to 10 (SEE PICTURE SAMPLE OUTPUT)

[image: SAMPLE OUTPUT]

I was asked to modify the following for loop (see below) to print out a table horizontally and write the function to execute multiple tables:

```
<script>
const multiplier = 2;
for(let i=i, i<=10; i++){
    console.log(i*multiplier);
}
</script>
```

I got the for loop modified and it works (see below my code) but I get a long string of numbers:

```js
let multiplier = 1;
let locationTables = '';

const tables = function tables(){
    for(let y=1; y<= 10; y++){
    let multiplication = y*multiplier;
    locationTables += multiplication + ' ';
    }; 
    return multiplier +=1;
}

const factory = function factory(f){
    while(multiplier <= 10){
        let subtable = f();
        
    }
}

var factortables = factory(tables);
console.log(locationTables);
```

[image: MY OUTPUT]

I want to organize then in rows of 10 numbers and 10 columns (table 10x10).

Comment: Are you only outputting to the console? The console is meant for debugging; I don't think you can format it, although you might try using `console.table(locationTables)`

Comment: Hi @mykaf ! I am new to coding. My instructor asked me to use the console because we are learning to debug along with the exercises.  I followed your recommendation of using  console.table(locationTables) but I am still getting the result in one long string.

Comment: `console.log("line1\nline2");` prints 2 lines.

Comment: A simple `\n` will add a line break in the console but you'll quickly see that the numbers won't line up vertically

Comment: @001, How could link the `let locationTables = '';` to the console `console.log("line1\nline2");` is there a way to organize the result of my variable `let locationTables = '';`  in rows and columns or should I just rewrite my code to obtain the table style result?

Comment: @j08691 like this `let locationTables = ''+'\n';`? ... with this I obtained this `'\n1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way:

```js
const res=Array(10).fill(0).map((_,i)=>
 Array(10).fill(0).map((__,j)=>String((i+1)*(j+1)).padStart(3," ")).join("")).join("\n");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This seems complex for me at my current coding level. I'll stick with your initial answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new line to each output but then the are still not aligned. You can use padStart to fix this.

```js
let multiplier = 1;
let locationTables = '';

const tables = function tables(){
    for(let y=1; y<= 10; y++){
    let multiplication = y*multiplier;
    // padStart is used to prepend a string until it has it's required length
    locationTables += multiplication.toString().padStart(2, ' ') + ' ' ;
    };
    // Add new line after a full row 
    locationTables += '\n';
    return multiplier +=1;
}

const factory = function factory(f){
    while(multiplier <= 10){
        let subtable = f();
        
    }
}

var factortables = factory(tables);
console.log(locationTables);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of building up string we can push each value into an array within a main array.  Each array is a "row" of data.

Ad the end you can either view the raw array data or format each row as a string

```js
let multiplier = 1;
const max = 10;
const maxDigits = (max * max).toString().length + 1;
let rowIndex = 0; 
let locationTables = [[]];

const tables = function tables(){
   
  for(let y=1; y<= max; y++){
    let multiplication = y * multiplier;
    locationTables[rowIndex].push(multiplication);
  };
  if(rowIndex < max-1){
    rowIndex++;
    locationTables[rowIndex] = [];
  }
  return multiplier +=1;
}

const factory = function factory(f){
  while(multiplier <= max){
    let subtable = f();
  }
}

var factortables = factory(tables);
//console.log('raw arrays', locationTables);

const grid = locationTables.map(row => {
  return row.map(d => {
    return d.toString().padStart(maxDigits, ' ');
  }).join('')
}).join('\n');
console.log(grid);
```